# Class declare in a module is is giving is not a constructor in another module Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have  my module 1 in which I have a class;

```
class myClass {
  constructor (yes=true, name='') {
    this.yes = yes;
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

And in my second module I am importing the first module :

```
const {myClass} = require('tools');

let user = new myClass();
```

The line :  `let user = new myClass();`
is giving the error :  is not a constructor

How can I get the class to work in the second module, I don't wanna remove the class from the first module.

Comment: How are you exporting `myClass`?

Comment: try `export class myClass` you might not exporting the class.

Answer (score 2):

Please export the class as following then only it will be accessible in other modules.

```
module.exports = myClass;
```

Access it directly like this will definitely work.

```
const myClass=  require('./testtt');
```